# How to assign shift via graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

so I am developing a message extension for teams app. I'm already done listing the open shifts and user can select one of the open shifts, I looked at the documentation of graph API for shift and I didn't see anything like assigning shift to a person, is this possible with microsoft graph API?

Comment: Hi @user11781598, we can create shifts for teams using Graph API, could you please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/shift?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**For better visibility coping answer from comments** Hi @user11781598, we can create shifts for teams using Graph API, could you please follow [Shift documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/shift?view=graph-rest-1.0).